# two arrays from user input and get an output of the common values of the two arrays

Tags: java, user-input

I'm still new to java and been trying to write code that takes two different arrays of common values and outputs the common values of both arrays but I keep getting the following error message:

> Exception in thread "main" Your common values are: 0 Your common
> values are: 0 Your common values are: 0 Your common values are: 0
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for
> length 5  at HomworkTestingQ.main(HomworkTestingQ.java:18)

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);{       
            int n = 5;
            int m = 5;
            int[] array1 = new int[m];
            int[] array2 = new int[n];  
        
            System.out.println("Enter the first array: ");
            n=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the second array");
            m=sc.nextInt();
            for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; i < array2.length; j++) {
                    if(array1[i] == array2[j]) {
                        System.out.println("Your common values are: " + array1[i+j] );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix your codes:

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = 5;
        int m = 5;
        int[] array1 = new int[m];
        int[] array2 = new int[n];

        System.out.println("Enter the first array: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            array1[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the second array");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            array2[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        for (int item : array1) {
            for (int value : array2) {
                if (item == value) {
                    System.out.println("Your common values are: " + item);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that you're adding the array iterators here:

```
array1[i+j]
```

The i+j is adding to be more than the length of array1.

An aside, your arrays aren't being populated as I think you expect based on:

```
        System.out.println("Enter the first array: ");
        n=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the second array");
        m=sc.nextInt();
```

I'm just speculating there perhaps you have more to do there down the line.

Comment: how else am I supposed to populate them? and in the (array1[i+j]) i have tried  doing [i] only but I still got the error message.

Comment: Refer to @z-fp's answer below to populate your arrays correctly.
He also solved your issue entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add up the indices..
Since array1[i] is equal to array2[j], print any one of them:

```
for(int i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
    for(int j=i+1;j<array2.length;j++){
        if(array1[i]==array2[j]) int commonValue = array1[i];
        return commonValue; // or print it
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**FIRST PROBLEM**
The size of the array won't change when you scan the value of `m` and `n` because java is pass by value and the size of the array is the value, not the variable.
So you should do something like-

```
int m = scanner.nextInt();
int[] arr = new int[m];
```

**SECOND PROBLEM**

```
System.out.println("Your common values are: " + array1[i+j] );
```

This will go out of bounds, perhaps you should do-

```
System.out.println("Your common values are: " + array1[i] );
```